# TypeScript, NextJS, OpenAI api, fetch request, keep getting "cannot read undefined (reading 'headers') error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, prisma, openai-api

I am trying to generate a chat completion response using the OpenAI api. I am using Typescript and Nextjs 13. Here is the code below:

The api endpoint:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { Configuration, CreateChatCompletionResponse, OpenAIApi } from "openai"
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios"

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
})
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

export async function POST(request: Request, response: Response) {
    console.log("OPENAI ROUTE HIT")
    try {
        const { title, role } = await request.json()

        const aiResponse = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [
                {
                    role: "user",
                    content: `Create small blog post with html tags based on this title: ${title}`,
                },
                {
                    role: "system",
                    content: `${
                        role || "I am a helpful assistant"
                    }. Write with html tags`,
                },
            ],
        })

        return NextResponse.json(
            {
                content: aiResponse.data.choices[0].message?.content,
            },
            { status: 200 }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        NextResponse.json({ error: "error updating post" }, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

This is how I'm hitting the endpoint:

```
    const postAiContent = async () => {
        //loading state
        editor.chain().focus().setContent("Generating. Please wait...").run()

        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/openai`,
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        title: title,
                        role: role,
                    }),
                }
            )
            console.log("after response")
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("something went wrong")
            }

            const data = await response.json()

            editor.chain().focus().setContent(data.content).run()
            setContent(data.content)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')" error in my terminal. Furthermore, even if I comment out the OpenAI stuff in the backend, my network tab still shows that there is a 500 server error from OpenAI.

I also tried `aiResponse: AxiosResponse<CreateChatCompletionResponse, any>` which threw an error saying that "AxiosRequestHeaders | undefined is not assignable to type AxiosRequestHeaders".

I can hit the api endpoint without issues and correctly passing in the 'title' and 'role' parameters. I have another endpoint with Prisma which is set up very similarly which works without issue.

Any help on this would be great.